# Spring Boot 3.1.5 - secured connection to IBM MQ

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have Spring Boot application which connects to IBM MQ. It uses mq-jms-spring-boot-starter. Until now it was connected to broker where was username/password authentication. This connection works perfectly.

However there is a need to switch to use secure connection. I have updated configuration file as below:

```
ibm.mq.queue-manager=QM1
ibm.mq.channel=QM.SRV01
ibm.mq.conn-name=qm.local(1414)
ibm.mq.user=username
ibm.mq.password=passw0rd
ibm.mq.ssl-cipher-spec=ANY_TLS13_OR_HIGHER
ibm.mq.jks.trust-store=key.jks
ibm.mq.jks.trust-store-password=keyPassw0rd
ibm.mq.jks.key-store=key.jks
ibm.mq.jks.key-store-password=keyPassw0rd
```

JKS contains private key, certificate and CA certificates.
JKS file is placed in resources folder and is being copied to target during application build.

MQ configuration is done as below (taken from IBM MQ documentation):

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class IBMMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);.
        return factory;
    }
}
```

When I start application it runs but then it throws following exceptions:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'qm.local' rejected. 
...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed.
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation
...
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation
...
Caused by: java.security.KeyManagementException: problem accessing trust store
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:942) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1111) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceOf(Provider.java:1879) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:1886) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1861) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:110) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:83) ~[na:na]
```

JKS file is present. When I set a breakpoint in IBMMQConfig class and call

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("key.jks")
```

I do get the resource. So why it is throwing such exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have implemented new connection factory class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MQConfig {

    @Value("${mq.conn-name}")
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${mq.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${mq.channel}")
    private String channel;

    @Value("${mq.queue-manager}")
    private String queueManager;

    @Value("${mq.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${mq.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${mq.ssl-cipher-suite}")
    private String cipherSuite;

    @Value("${mq.jks-file}")
    private String jksFile;

    @Value("${mq.jks-file-password}")
    private String jksFilePassword;

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory myFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();


        try {
            String keyStoreKey = jksFilePassword;
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jksFile), keyStoreKey.toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStoreKey.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
            TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
            sslContext.init(km, tm, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            factory.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName);
            factory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
            factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
            factory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);
            factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
            factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
            factory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
            factory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
            factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, cipherSuite);
            factory.setHostName(hostName);

            MQEnvironment.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
            MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = cipherSuite;

            factory.createConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot connect to Queue Manager");
        }

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ANY_TLS13_OR_HIGHER` is not a valid ciphersuite for IBM MQ classes JMS.  The equivalent you need to use for IBM MQ classes JMS is `*TLS13ORHIGHER` (make sure to include the `*`).

See the IBM docs page [TLS CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=jms-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes) for a table that shows the mapping for all supported CipherSpecs.

Comment: Ok, that's the point for the Cipher Suite. But the very initial exception is: java.security.KeyManagementException: problem accessing trust store

Comment: My answer should solve `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException`.  Maybe you should provide the full path to `key.kdb`.

Comment: A relative path should suffice, but it should be with respect to where you are running the spring application. ie if in same directory then `./key.jks`